# How to make dynamic menu with angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I make dynamic menu based on angular.js

I want show menu two ways. one is before login,  other is after login

my menu code is here

**navbar.js**

```
$scope.menu = [{
  'title': 'Home',
  'link': '/'
},
{
  'title': 'About',
  'link': '/about'
},
{
  'title': 'Contact',
  'link': '/contact'
},
{
  'title': 'Workspace',
  'link': '/workspace'
},
{
  'title': 'SignIn',
  'link': '/signin'
}
];
...
```

and my html file is here

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: isActive(item.link)}">
        <a ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I want add signout menu, and only show after login.
how I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generate $scope.menu based on your users status so that it only contains the links you need.

```
var getAvailableLinks = function () {
    // Generate the links here.
};

$scope.menu = getAvailableLinks();
```